# Python Selenium "TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, html, selenium, url, typeerror

I need help with my code. I use Selenium with python

```
elems = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//article[@class='page-container']/section/div[3]") 

for job in elems:
  
   job_list.append(job.get_attribute('href')) 

print(job_list)
```

```
The error is "TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable".
```

I know that the result of elems is a WebElement, but I need to use find_element_by_xpath because I want a specific div and this div has not an unique id. I didn't find a way to convert WebElement in (for example) a string.
Do you have any idea of an another way to have this specific div but not using find_element_by_xpath?
Do you have any other idea to skirt the problem ?

Comment: xpath returns only one element and it seems like there's no such element so it returns a webelement i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for job in elems:
```

If you pay attention, the compiler will think elems is a list.

But you've defined `elems` as

```
elems = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//article[@class='page-container']/section/div[3]")
```

which will return a **WebElement** not list of **WebElement**.

**Issue Explanation :**

Note that `find_element_by_xpath` returns a web element where as `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list.

**Fix :** (use `find_elements` not `find_element`)

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[@class='page-container']/section/div[3]") 

for job in elems:
    job_list.append(job.get_attribute('href')) 
print(job_list)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !  It helped ! My code has no more error but the result of job_list is None, however it's not relate to this problem :)